# WCF 16384 max array length

Tags: arrays, wcf, exception

Been trying to solve this for a day. I cant seen to find any error with my code, please help. Thank you!
I'm using IIS to host the Service and used add service reference for the client.
I have made sure that I added readerquota and correct binding configuration. Still, the error occur when i'm sending image file with size over 16384kb.

```
Server
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ICotfServerWCF" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
      maxStringContentLength="5242880"
      maxArrayLength="2147483646"
      maxBytesPerRead="4096"
      maxNameTableCharCount="5242880" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
             realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="ServerWCF.ICotfServerWCF">
        <endpoint address="http://192.168.2.140:8081/CotfServerWCF.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="filebehavior" name="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ICotfServerWCF" contract="ServerWCF.ICotfServerWCF" />
      </service>
    </services>



    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="filebehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2000000000"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="databaseCS" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=CotfDatabase;User ID=CotfDbUser; Password=$ing1234;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>



Client
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_Client" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferSize="6553600" maxBufferPoolSize="5242880" maxReceivedMessageSize="6553600"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="100000"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="100000" />
                    <security mode="None">
                        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                            realm="" />
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
          <endpoint address="http://192.168.2.140:8081/CotfServerWCF.svc"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_Client"
              contract="ServerWCF.ICotfServerWCF" name="BasicHttpBinding_ICotfServerWCF" >
          </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>


</configuration>
```

I have figured out the issue, after I updated my server and client to the right values and right binding. My client is still sending default configuration. Also, the configuration.svcinfo file is still in default value and not updated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you  change quotas config  both server and client side.

Comment: Yes, i tried same value for both server and client, also different values. Still, it has not work. The values i set are all above 16384. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question, might taking a look again? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First are you sure that you have set your HttpRuntime to be more than 4MB. You can do it as shown below:

```
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1572864"/>
```

The above element is under system.web element. The .NET framework's http runtime doesnt allow data more than 4MB by default.

Your reader quotas on the server and client are a bit different. Make sure that you have the client reader quotas same as that of the server.

Once you have the above and you still have problems then try enabling Tracing on your service and it should tell you the exact reason why your request is failing. To enable tracing follow the article [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: For a miniute I thought there's finally an answer, sadly, it still does not work. Anyway, the trace exception show : 

"System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Message:
"The remote server returned an unexpected response: (400) Bad Request."

Not really helpful actually. :\

Comment: If you drill down the trace file you should find the reason for the bad request. Also can you post your Service Contract and your request that is being posted. Try using fiddler to capture your request. (Hope you have updated the client config to have the same reader quotas as the server)

Comment: Hi i have updated and used trace again on Server. I found this:

The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded. To increase the quota, use the MaxReceivedMessageSize property on the appropriate binding element.

Comment: Seems like your client has that in the binding element. Just try to increase that to the same values as on the server.

Comment: In the config posted above the values are different.

Comment: I changed it, and i figured out the message is not the right one. sorry, it came from wcftestclient. But When i send the right information from the right client. I checked the trace and only this came up. : configuration evaluation not found warning and The maximum array length quota (16384) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxArrayLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader.

Comment: Hi, i have updated my question, might taking a look again? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The client should also get a behaviorConfiguration that sets the maxItemsInObjectGraph

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
        <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
```

Then.. reference this new behavior on your client endpoint...

```
<endpoint address="http://youraddresshere"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService"
            contract="" name="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" />
```

You could also try increasing your `maxBytesPerRead=""` value in your client and service settings.